# How can this Q about Outlook mail forwarding be off topic?

Tags: support, scope, specific-question, closed-questions

I recently asked [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44292/how-to-forward-multiple-emails-at-outlookemail-client?noredirect=1#comment35129_44292) relating to Outlook mail forwarding functionality. I guessed it would relate to webapps.stackexchange.com since the Outlook email sending tool is not listed as off topic. According to [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) this is the list of things which are off topic here:

> Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
>
> - Desktop software
> - Applications for mobile devices such as the Android or iPad
> - Hosted scripts such as Wordpress.org and phpBB
> - Web applications containing adult content
> - Developing & programming web applications
> - Browsers and their features
> - App recommendations unless prior research is shown

Outlook doesn't comes under this category and how could it be off topic here?

If Outlook mail forwarding is off topic here then where could I proceed this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked in the comment -

> Are you talking about outlook.com or the desktop email client outlook?  - [Sathya](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44292/how-to-forward-multiple-emails-at-outlookemail-client?noredirect=1#comment35110_44292)

To which you replied:

> @Sathya email client - [vignesh4303](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44292/how-to-forward-multiple-emails-at-outlookemail-client?noredirect=1#comment35126_44292)

Per the first point of the FAQ that you have quoted:

> Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
>
> - Desktop software

and hence was closed as so.

Answer (score 5):

At first glance I would say [Super User](https://superuser.com/), however, you are suspended on Super User at the moment so the migration of the question would have have been automatically blocked.

Please don't post off topic questions on other sites try and circumvent a question ban or suspension on another site. Such behaviour can lead to a wider and/or longer suspension.

On a second reading of the question I see you don't state whether this is the web client or the desktop client you are using. The only indication is the "email client" in brackets in the title and the fact that you seem to confirm that it's the desktop client in the comments.

If this is really about the web client then you need to be clear about that in the question and in your responses to questions.

Comment: agreed,but my confusion is the related question is regarding mail sending tool outlook(webapplication mail sending client) how could it would be on superuser, if questions regarding outlook is banned here then how this question allowed?http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/is-it-possible-to-sync-ms-outlook-with-specific-google-calendar its related to outlook and email calendar

Comment: @vignesh4303 - I've updated the answer. You appear to be saying that it's the desktop client in the question and the web client here. Which is it?

Comment: @vignesh4303 - that question is about Google Calendar which is definitely on topic for us.